# Unable to ajax submit form after using validate in IE, Firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jquery's validate plugin to validate my form. The form is validated successfully. 
But when i ajax submit form using the callback handler, i.e, submit handler like this:

```
submitHandler: function(form)
{
     $('button[type=submit],input[type=submit]').attr('disabled','disabled');
     ajaxSubmit();
}
```

This works fine in chrome but not in IE and Firefox(both latest versions).
the page is reloaded and the contents of the form are reset and nothing happens.

```
ajaxSubmit();
```

is the function in which i collect form data and send it for processing.

Comment: Any error you are getting in console?

Comment: the page gets reloaded i cannot tell...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `preventDefault()` in your `submit` handler or the form will be submitted in addition to your AJAX submission. It looks like the default submission is interrupting the AJAX call in IE and Firefox, preventing the call from doing anything.

From the code you've posted I can't tell you where to put the required call.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 submitHandler: function(form)
 {
      $('button[type=submit],input[type=submit]').attr('disabled','disabled');
      $(form).ajaxSubmit();
      //or try=> form.ajaxSubmit();
      return false;
 }
```

Read http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxSubmit

Comment: but form.submit() is not an ajax submission.